# Node ESM await for import() to return?

Tags: async-await

Is, in the following code, import('crypto') actually await from crypto to load and then return 
it?

```
const _module = (async () => {
        try {
            return await import('crypto');
        } catch (e) {
            return window.crypto || window.msCrypto || Math;
        }
    })();
```

Im pretty confused right now,  because _module is a Promise and in my head it should be the Node.js module crypto.
What do I do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Where it should run in browser or in the node.js ?

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. That was an attempt to obtain a cryptographic module. An attempt that it was working in both the browser and node.js. But i realized, too late, that an async function will always wrap the return value in a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

`import crypto from 'node:crypto'` works fine. I was also confused by nodejs doc showing usage with `await`, but it's not needed.

More info: [What is the await keyword effect when importing ESM modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876249/what-is-the-await-keyword-effect-when-importing-esm-modules)