# What is the await keyword effect when importing ESM modules

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

Node.js docs' crypto module documentation uses top level `await` to import, but it's clearly not a dynamic import

source:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_static_method_certificate_exportchallenge_spkac_encoding

What is the difference between the 2 statement below (they seems to do the same)

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
const fs_ = await import('fs');        // why use this?
```

Comment: "*but it's clearly not a dynamic import*" what do you mean? `import()` is always dynamic.

Comment: the `import(lib)` returns a promise the `await import(lib)` returns the library (like `import * as lib from 'lib'`)

Comment: I know. That's why I said that `import()` is always dynamic. The non-function-like syntax is always static.

Comment: I suppose it's just a syntax sugar to have CJS module-like syntax in ESM but I'm really not sure

Comment: Dynamic imports are resolved differently to static ones. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Not Duplicate]

- The await `import()` imports an EC Module statically (instead of `import()` imports dynamically), it's very similar to the CommonJS module `require()` syntax, this is the only purpose of the top level await keyword

Supported by: (node.js 14.8.0) (chrome 89) (Firefox 89) at the time of writing this

- So why using it if we already have all those beautiful static import syntaxes? (like: `import * as imp from './someModule.mjs`)
- Well it's more straightforward to write and easier to remember (ex: `await import('./someModule.mjs')` statically requires the 'someModule' and returns its exported data as `{default:'someDefVal'[, ...]}` object

```
// static import -----------------------------------// blocks this module untill './module1.mjs' is fully loaded 
  // traditional static import in EC modules 
    import * as imp from './module1.mjs'; 
    console.log( imp );                             // -> {default:'data from module-1'}
    
  // static import with await import() (does the same as above but is prettier) 
    console.log( await import('./module1.mjs') );   // -> {default:'data from module-1'}
    
    function importFn1(){                           // the await import() is a satic import so cannot be used in a function body
        // await import('./module1.mjs');           // this would throw a SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word 
    }
    
    
// dynamic import ----------------------------------// does not block this module, the './module2.mjs' loads once this module is fully loaded (not asynchronous)
    import('./module2.mjs') 
        .then((res)=>{ console.log(res) })          // -> {default:'data from module-2'}
        .catch((err)=>{ console.log(err) });
        
    (function ImporFn2(){
        import('./module2.mjs')                     // dynamic import inside a function body 
            .then((res)=>{ console.log(res) })      // -> {default:'data from module-2'}
            .catch((err)=>{ console.log(err) });
    })();
    
    console.log( '----- MAIN MODULE END -----' );
```

- result in console

```
{ default: 'data from module-1' }
{ default: 'data from module-1' }
----- MAIN MODULE END -----
{ default: 'data from module-2' }
{ default: 'data from module-2' }
```

Comment: While this answer is correct regarding what blocks and what does not, its use of `dynamic` and `static` words is just plain wrong. An `import()` is always dynamic, whether you use it with `await` or not. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).